# All elementary toposes have finite colimits

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

An *elementary topos* is a category with finite limits, exponential objects, and a subobject classifier. Here a quote from Leinster's *[An informal introduction to topos theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.5647.pdf)*:

> More spectacularly, the axioms imply that every topos has finite colimits. This
> can be proved by the following very elegant strategy, due to Paré (1974). For
> every topos $E$, we have the contravariant power set functor $P = Ω^{(−)}
> : E^{
> op} → E$ .
> It can be shown that $P$ is monadic. But monadic functors create limits, and $E$
> has finite limits. Hence $E^{
> op}$ has finite limits; that is, $E$ has finite colimits.

As far as I now, the fact that $P$ creates limits means that $A$ is the limit of a diagram of objects $A_i$ in $E^{op}$ if and only if $PA$ is the limit of all $P(A_i)$ in $E$. Since $E$ has finite limits, there is a limit $L$ of all $P(A_i)$ (provided the diagram $(A_i)$ is finite). Hence *if* $L$ has the form $PA$, then we can conclude that $(A_i)$ has a limit, namely $A$, in $E^{op}$, i.e., a colimit in $E$.

**Question:** How does one conclude that $E$ has all finite colimits? The problem I see is that $L$ isn't necessarily of the form $PA$.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for “Monad” says the power ser functor is a monad $E\to E,$ not $E^{op}\to E,$ at least as a Monad functor.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The monad structure on $P : E \to E$ is actually a structure on a different functor than the functor $P : E^{op} \to E$ referred to here. For $P : E \to E$, the action on morphisms is the image map. For $P : E^{op} \to E$, the action on morphisms is the inverse image map. $P : E^{op} \to E$ is the one which is monadic - it is the right adjoint of $P^{op} : E \to E^{op}$. There's a difference between being a monad and being monadic.

Comment: @MarkSaving but a monad is a functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal C.$ So I still don’t see how the $E^{op}\to E$ can be a monad. Unless monadic functor has a meaning different, like a functor with an adjoint that together is a monad.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As I said, there's a difference between being a monad and being monadic. It's confusing terminology, but there it is. Monadic functors are certain kinds of functors which are right adjoints - see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+functor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of what it means for a funtor to create limits is incomplete: creating limits means not only preserving and reflecting, but also that the a diagram in the domain has a limit whenever its image in the codomain does. It is in this sense that monadic functors create limits.

Comment: That's wrong. Check the definition at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/created+limit.

Comment: @user1005113 The definition states "Let F:C→D be a functor and J:I→C a diagram, and suppose that the composite F∘J has a limit. We say that F creates this limit if J has a limit, and F both preserves and reflects limits of J". This agrees with what I'm saying. "and F both preserves and reflects limits" means there's an additional condition for F creating a limit. The additional condition is that "J [the diagram in the domain] has a limit" given we have "suppose[d] F∘J (the diagram in the codomain) has a limit".